# How to convert from text to boolean with consideration of value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

I want to convert the datatype of a column in a table from `text` to `boolean`. The data in the column is `'t'` for true and `'f'` for false.

I tried to convert it with this statement:

`ALTER TABLE public.checktypes ALTER COLUMN deleted SET DATA TYPE boolean USING deleted::boolean;`

This works for the conversion of the data type just fine. The problem is, all of them are now `false`. How can I accomplish that, if the value before the conversion is `'t'`, the boolean will set to `true?`

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER mycolumn TYPE bool USING CASE WHEN mycolumn=0 THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END;
ALTER TABLE mytabe ALTER COLUMN mycolumn SET DEFAULT FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
update checktypes
set deleted = case deleted when 't' then '1' when 'f' then '0' end
```

then:

```
ALTER TABLE public.checktypes ALTER COLUMN deleted SET DATA TYPE boolean USING deleted::boolean;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:
create temp table, insert and convert text to boolean to temp table, drop old column, add new column of boolean type and invoke update

show this code:

```
create table _temp
(
    id integer,
    val_boolean boolean
)

insert into _temp(id,value) select id,val::boolean from your_table;

alter table your_table drop column val;

alter table your_table add column val boolean;

update your_table t set val = (select val_boolean from _temp te where te.id = t.id);
```